# Is having a core project that shares common classes and properties to microservices a good practice?

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

There is a simple java project `core`, which has utility classes and configurations that are directly imported to the microservices(Spring Boot). In this case, `api` and `admin`.

Here is a `build.bradle` setting to show the project structure.

```
project(':core') {
    dependencies {
    }
}

project(':api') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    build.dependsOn ':core:build'
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}

project(':admin') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    build.dependsOn ':core:build'
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}
```

I think microservices supposed to be independent of one another, so this `core` project might have some potential problem in the future. For example, we have a datasource properties in the `core` project. What if a new microservice requires another datasource? While we can override `core` properties using another properties file and profile, I think this only makes settings unnecessary complicated. Maybe even more if common classes need to be changed.

Is having a core project that shares common classes and properties to microservices a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's totally fine. Think about this core module as 3rth party dependency which you plugged into your microservices. To deal with potential problems when the core module will have breaking changes you have to make api/admin module depending on a specific version of the core module so instead of depending on `com.myapp.core:RELEASE` use `com.myapp.core:1.2.4` and slightly migrate your upstream modules to the fresh version of the core. In this case, you won't have any issues and your microservices will be still independent with each other.

Comment: Maybe that's what we were missing. We didn't make `core` as a dependency; we just imported classes directly.

Comment: Do you have a monolith with three applications within it - core,api and admin? You build a fat jar and then run some of those applications e.g. java -iar fat.jar CoreMicroserviceApp or java -iar fat.jar ApiMicroserviceApp or java -iar fat.jar AdminMicroserviceApp, am I right?

Comment: Not sure if this is a proper answer, but we have a build.gradle setting like this: `project(':core') {
    dependencies {
    }
}` `project(':admin') {
    apply plugin: 'war'
    build.dependsOn ':core:build'
    dependencies {
        compile project(':core')
    }
}`

Comment: I just saw your edit. Yes but `core`. `core` is actually just a simple java project rather than microservice. It is not even using spring boot; just some java utility classes, enums, and a yaml. I'll edit about the `core` project. Sorry about the misinformation.

Comment: I see now. Such configuration is one of the approaches for developing and it's also fine. It has some cons you mentioned in your question that changes in the core module immediately will affect api/admin but on the other side, you will always have up to date codebase. I agree with @Estradiaz comment that microservices in mostly about how you deploy your application, but not about how you organize your codebase. Both approaches have rights you to life, e.g. facebook(and many more companies) uses monolith code base and it works for them. The key is how you deploy your apps.